# How to use ontouch event in canvas HTML5?

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-canvas

I am new to this site and this is first question I am asking here..if its simple pls forgive me..
I have drawn one background image, on this I am drawing 5 small small images by using drawImage() method. Once I touch the small images then they should disappear or should pop up one alert box but ontouch event is not occurring so far I have searched for ontouch event but no use. I dont want to draw images through img tag in HTML.
Here is my code segment

```
var car = new Image();
car.src = "img/car.jpg";
    car.onload = function() {
    imgLoaded = true;
}
if (imgLoaded = true) {
    drawBackgroundImg();
    drawCarImg();

}


 function drawCarImg() {
if (i == 0) {
    x1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 501));
    y1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 301));
    cxt.save();
    cxt.drawImage(car, x1, y1, car.width, car.height);
    cxt.restore();

   }
  }
 car.on('touchstart', function() {
 alert("T");
 });

Here is my HTML code

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>   
<div id="container" onclick="void(0)">
    <canvas id="can"> </canvas>

</div>
<div id="btn">
    <input type="image" id="zoomIn" src="img/up.png" onclick="zoomIn()" />
    <input type="image" id="zoomOut" src="img/down.png"
        onclick="zoomOut()" />
</div>
<div id="score">
    <p id="scoreCount">
        <b></b>
    </p>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Could anybody help me to get the solution.
FYI: I am running this code in Phonegap NOT in browser.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in question, I dont want to use img tag for drawing image. How can u use id for images???  $( '#id' ).on( 'touchstart',function(){ //your code }); This I got while searching but I have draw images  by using drawImage() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, I made div with invisible and placed the images with position absolute and use the id's of images and trigger the touchstart event.
above said example here

```
  $('#id').on('touchmove',function(){
  alert("T");

   }); 
 $('#id').on('click',function(){
   alert("T");

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#id' ).on( 'touchstart',function(){
                     //your code
                       });
```

here id is id of your html element on which you want to listen touch event.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in question, I dont want to use img tag for drawing image. How can u use id for images??? $( '#id' ).on( 'touchstart',function(){ //your code }); This I got while searching but I have to draw images by using drawImage() method

Comment: If I got your question right, you must me drawing the Image on a div on html page right? and want to listen for touch on that div?? so you can give id of that div. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: are you trying this on ios?

Comment: ok got it. In ios you will receive touch and click event only on clickable elements. So for work around you can make that div clickable using - <div onclick="void(0)"></div>

Comment: Actually I am using phonegap with android not IOS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').on('touchmove',function(){
      alert("T");

  }); 
$('#id').on('click',function(){
       alert("T");

});
```

Comment: Which id you are using I am not getting, actually I am drawing images dynamically once background image load. I am not using img element in html file. In the javascript only I am drawing images..

Comment: use touchmove event instead of touchsart event

Comment: I am using phonegap with android not IOS

Comment: Tell me, through image object can we call ontouch method or not??? I have seen so many games which are like once we touch images they may disappear or else does something.